# How to render data from a html file using servlets?

Tags: servlets

I'm new to Servlets. I'm trying to render data from a html file but I'm not sure about the folder structure where to place the HTML file.

[image]

I kept in web-inf folder while I run it returns null

Comment: will you provide your code so that we can find bugs

Comment: Hi Darshit,Thank you/I kept the file in Web-inf folder directly now I moved it to Webcontent folder.it's working fine now.